# blocking the values after a specific date

Tags: sas

I've got the following question.

I'm trying to run a partial least square forecast on a data model I have. Issue is that I need to block certain line in order to have the forecast for a specific time.

What I want would be the following. For June, every line before May 2014 will be blocked (see the screenshot below).

[image]

For May , every line before April 2014 will be blocked (see the screenshot below).

[image]

I was thinking of using a delete through a proc sql to do so but this solution seems to be very brutal and I wish to keep my table intact.

Question : Is there a way to block the line for a specific date with needing a deletion?

Many thanks for any insight you can give me as I've never done that before and don't know if there is a way to do that (I did not find anything on the net).

**Edit** : The aim of the blocking will be to use the missing values and to run the forecast on this missing month namely here in June 2014 and in May 2014 for the second example

Comment: I hope what I'm saying makes sense. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Are your dates stored as numbers or text?  You seem to have a mixture of French and English dates in your data.

Comment: Hi Keith, the nouv_date or put it in English, is the new date and is a date format in English. The mixture of French and English is due , 95% , to the export in csv. I wanted to take a screenshot of my SAS but the letters are too small.

Comment: I was thinking that if I'm deleting all the rows after the specific date , it would do the trick and I need only to save everything and then inject everything again , once it is done. Is this solution likely to do the trick...?

Comment: I don't understand why a simple WHERE clause won't suffice, you'll need one to delete the rows anyway.  If you could publish the code you're hoping to run for the regression then it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what proc you are planning to use, but you should be able to do something like the below.

It builds a control data set, based on a distinct set of dates, including a filter value and building a text data set name. This data set is then called from a data *null* step.

Call execute is a ridiculously powerful function for this sort of looping behaviour that requires you to build strings that it will than pass as if they were code. Note that column names in the control set are "outside" the string and concatenated with it using ||. The alternative is probably using quite a lot of macro.

```
proc sql;
    create table control_dates as
    select distinct 
        nuov_date, 
        put(nuov_date,mon3.)||'_results' as out_name
    from [csv_import];
quit;

data _null_;
    set control_dates;
    call execute(
        'data '||out_name||'; 
             set control_dates
                 (where=(nuov_date<'||nouv_date||')); 
         run;');
    call execute('proc [analysis proc] data='||out_name||';run;');
run;
```